# Missing deployment from IntelliJ 12

Tags: intellij-idea

Just updated to IntelliJ 12 from 11. I can't find 
**deployment** feature anymore.

Previously it was in menu `Tools > Deployment` now its gone. I can't find it in plugin list as well. However according to the [Web Help](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/options.html) it should be there.

Any idea how to enable it?

EDIT:
I have ultimate edition.

Comment: I see it in mine...on Mac.  Version 12.

Comment: @Makoto Awesome, but -  https://dl.dropbox.com/u/27794808/Screen%20Shot%202013-01-10%20at%206.53.03%20PM.png and https://dl.dropbox.com/u/27794808/Screen%20Shot%202013-01-10%20at%206.53.34%20PM.png

Comment: Make sure that **Remote Hosts Access** plugin (that's the actual name) is installed and enabled (should be like that by default though). Also check `idea.log` (Help | Reveal log in ...) -- it will list all loaded plugins so you can verify if it's loaded or not.

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you! Convert comment into answer so I can accept it. Guys from JetBrains need to update Web Help, there is nothing about Remote Host Access plugin. Even when I searched for "deployment" in plugins repo I couldn't find it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure that **Remote Hosts Access** plugin (that's the actual name for Deployment functionality) is installed and enabled (though it should be installed and enabled by default, as it is standard functionality .. unless you did some re-configuration at some point (e.g. during upgrading)).

You can also check `idea.log` (Help | Reveal log in ...) -- it will have a list of all loaded plugins so you can verify if it's loaded or not.